# Can I use powershell to inspect a running .Net process?

Tags: .net, debugging, powershell, clr, appdomain

Let's say I have a 100% managed .Net application running.

I can attach to it via a visual studio debugger and be able to do things like grab references to a ServiceLocator (if it's static) and so on.  I would like to be able to do this in Powershell.

It seems like this should be possible but I have no idea where to start.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PowerDbg](http://powerdbg.codeplex.com). That's a good start imho.

Short description copied from codeplex:

> PowerDbg is a PowerShell library that
>   enables you to easily create
>   PowerShell scripts to automate a
>   WinDbg / CDB debugging session. You
>   can use PowerDbg for Kernel Mode or
>   User Mode, Post-Mortem debugging or
>   Live Debugging and for native or
>   managed code.
>
> PowerShell has several advantages over
>   the WinDbg Scripting Language. A few
>   of them are:
>
> - Easier to create scripts
> - Leverage the .NET Framework
> - Debugging and tracing features
> - Code reuse through functions and cmdlets
> - Easier maintenance
> - Easier to build large scripts
> - Easier to format and display the important information
>
> Whether you’re an old hand frustrated
>   with WinDbg scripting, or you’re
>   having your ‘first memory dump’
>   freak-out, PowerDbg is for you. And
>   hopefully for everyone in the middle
>   too.too.

Comment: Gah! Who the hell uses TFS with codeplex? Or TFS for any reason other than "being forced to" for that matter? 
Anyways, thank's a lot, this does look interesting.

Comment: Hmm...not quite what I was looking for. Needing to install debugging tools, have a pdb, etc. seems like a lot. What exactly is the limitation that keeps me from simply being able to attach powershell to a running clr process and make calls against any object in it?

Comment: The question is - how would you attach C# application to the process? Then we could find a way how to do it from PowerShell.

Comment: Why does it need to be C#? Powershell compiles down to clr too at some point, so if I have a static property in my app named ServiceLocator.Current, it would seem that I should be able to reference MayApp.ServiceLocator.Current from powershell and it should compile down to a reference to that particular location in the application's heap

Comment: The title is "... inspect a running .Net process?". So, for me it means that from powershell (one process) you would like to inspect other application (other process). It's the same as if you build an console application that tries to inspect some other independent .NET process. 2 different processes.